# Consumir API fipe em C#

Tags: c#, .net, api

Estou realizando estudos em C# e MySql.
Criei uma `combobox` chamada `Marca` e outra chamada `Modelo`.

Quero executar a api da fipe para buscar as marcas e modelos de veículos. Existe este endereço abaixo informando como consultar, porém gostaria de uma orientação mais detalhada de como fazer isso em C#.

http://fipeapi.appspot.com/

**Obs:** estes campos (marca,modelo) serão gravados no banco

Obrigado

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. O que já tentou fazer? Adicione na pergunta para que as respostas tenham um embasamento de solução.

Comment: Até o momento não realizei nenhuma tentativa, porque não sei de onde partir...

Comment: Bom se não sabe de onde partir a pergunta fica ampla demais, a api usa **JSON** pode começar dando uma lida em documentações e exemplos que manipulam isso na linguagem que deseja C# no caso, procure exemplo de persistencia de dados em mysql com o C# e surgindo uma dúvida específica posta aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias formas de se fazer isso, inclusive eu não sei se a pergunta não se encaixa como **ampla demais**.

De qualquer forma, vou mostrar como fazer uma requisição **`GET`** usando o [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) porque ele facilita muito toda a questão de fazer as requisições, serializar/deserilizar os dados, etc.

É possível instalá-lo via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp), com o comando

> PM> Install-Package RestSharp

**Exemplo de requisição `GET` para `http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/marcas.json`**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var client = new RestClient
        {
            BaseUrl = new Uri("http://fipeapi.appspot.com/")
        };

        var req = new RestRequest("api/1/{tipo}/marcas.json", Method.GET);

        req.AddParameter("tipo", "carros", ParameterType.UrlSegment);

        var response = client.Execute(req);
        var contentResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Marca>>(response.Content);
        // ^ Nesta lista vão estar todas as marcas da resposta      
    }
}

public class Marca
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Fipe_Name { get; set; }
}
```

<sup>[**Código no GitHub para referência futura**](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/tree/master/CSharp/114550)</sup>

Perceba que `Marca` é um tipo que deve ser criado por você. `response.Content` é o retorno no formato original (**JSON**) e `contentResponse` será uma `List<Marca>`, ou seja, o **JSON** original deserializado.

Comment: Vou testar, obrigado!